# How to check which ECS service or task the logstream belongs to from cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We have log error in our log groups. The errors are not thrown by the expected tasks we have. How do we trace which task/service log this errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate Task Definition for each cluster/service and define here where the logs will be send to:

```
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "my-cluster",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "my-service"
        }
```

as well the name of container:

```
"name": "my-container"
```

It will appear in CloudWatch logs as:
`my-cluster/my-service/my-container/fe788b38-4194-43ff-a128-71c57df15f1a`, where long ID is the ID of running container (task).

If you want to share Task Definition across many cluster/services you can search for relevant logs from ECS service itself (Logs tab).

Also you can grab container (task) ID from log and search for this ID in ECS console (tasks tab).

Comment: sorry, forgot to mentioned that i need to trace from cloudwatch to which ecs task, not the other way arouund because we have a lot of clusters and services and task